# android memory -allocated memory unstable & activity launch lags

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

I think I have memory problem..
Im building an app that have main listview that contains posts and on post click launch other activity with list view that display the post, comments etc..

the first couple of post entrance go smoothly, but after a couple its take a lot of time for the activity to launch.. ive notice that when this lad happens, my memory monitor goes crazy (as shown at the attach pic).
it goes like this for about 30 seconds and then it become normal again ant the activity appears as it should.

this problem happens every time, every 2-4 post entrance..

I dont know if its important to mention, but Im sending the post object from the main activity to the sub activity with parcelable and as far as I can say, the lags happens when I use the intent.getParcelableExtra("post").

[memory monitor http://srv1.jpg.co.il/5/548974bcf03c6.jpg](http://srv1.jpg.co.il/5/548974bcf03c6.jpg)

this is the calling intent

```
 Intent movingToNewActivityPost = new Intent(
                            CustomArrayAdapterForeMainJsonParser.context,
                            InsidePost.class);
                    movingToNewActivityPost.putExtra("post",postsArray.get(position-1));
                Log.i("post to inside",postsArray.get(position-1).getTitle());
                    movingToNewActivityPost.putExtra("from", "main");
                    movingToNewActivityPost.putExtra("position",position-1);
                    CustomArrayAdapterForeMainJsonParser.context
                            .startActivity(movingToNewActivityPost);
                if(getCurrentAsync()!=null)
                getCurrentAsync().cancel(true);
```

and this is the getView :

```
 View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final int type = getItemViewType(position);

    // if first time you load this line
    if (row == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (type == 0) {
            //main post
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_post_inside,
                    null, true);
            //holder.postImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
            holder.postTitle= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postTitle1);
            holder.postDate= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postDate);
            holder.postTags= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewTags);
            holder.postLikes = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postLikesMain));
            holder.postComments = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postCommuntsMain));
            holder.postShares = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postSharesMain));
            shares=holder.postShares;
            holder.like_share_communt = (LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.share_like_communt);
            holder.postLikesImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLike);
            holder.linearForDots= (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.linearForDots);
            holder.postDescription= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postBody);
            holder.postCommentsTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.commentsTitle);
            holder.viewPager= (ViewPager) row.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            parms.width = MainActivity.screenWidth;
            parms.height = (int) Math.round(MainActivity.screenWidth/1.6);
            holder.linearForViewPager=(LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.linearForViewPager);
            holder.linearForViewPager.setLayoutParams(parms);


            holder.postCommuntsMain= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postCommuntsMain);
            holder.PostDivider=(View)row.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            holder.postTagsImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            changeFonts(holder.postTitle, "Bold");
            changeFonts( holder.postDescription, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postDate,"Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postTags, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postLikes, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postComments,"Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postShares, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.postCommentsTitle, "Regular");

            row.setTag(holder);

        }

        if (type == 1) {
            //comment
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inside_post_users_communts, null, true);
            holder.commentUserName= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.commentDate= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            holder.commentDescription= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_communts_description);
            holder.commentVotesUp= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewVoteUp);
            holder.commentVotesUpImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVotesUp);
            holder.commentVotesDown= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewVoteDown);
            holder.commentVotesDownImage= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVotesDown);
            changeFonts(holder.commentUserName, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.commentDate,"Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.commentDescription, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.commentUserName, "Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp,"Regular");
            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Regular");
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    if(type==0) {
        final Post myPost = (Post) postsArray.get(0);
        holder.postTitle.setText(myPost.getFullTitle());
        holder.postDescription.setText(myPost.getDescription());
        holder.postDate.setText(myPost.getPubDate()+" • "+myPost.getPubDateTime());
        holder.postLikes.setText(myPost.getLikes());
        holder.postShares.setText(myPost.getShares());
        holder.postComments.setText(myPost.getComments());
        if (myPost.getIsLiked() == 1) {
            holder.postLikesImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_yellow);
            holder.postLikesImage.setTag("like");
        } else {
            holder.postLikesImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_white);
            holder.postLikesImage.setTag("likeoff");
        }

        // like
        holder.like_share_communt.getChildAt(2).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (holder.postLikesImage.getTag() == null
                                || holder.postLikesImage.getTag().equals(
                                "likeoff")) {
                            holder.postLikesImage
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_yellow);
                            holder.postLikesImage.setTag("like");
                            int temp = Integer.parseInt(myPost.getLikes());
                            temp++;
                            holder.postLikes.setText(temp + "");
                            insidePost.post.setIsLiked(1);
                            insidePost.post.setLikes(temp + "");
                            Like_unlike.like(myPost.getId());
                            return;
                        }
                        if (holder.postLikesImage.getTag().equals("like")) {
                            holder.postLikesImage
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_white);
                            holder.postLikesImage.setTag("likeoff");
                            holder.postLikes.setText(myPost.getLikes());
                            int temp = Integer.parseInt(myPost.getLikes());
                            temp--;
                            holder.postLikes.setText(temp + "");
                            insidePost.post.setIsLiked(0);
                            insidePost.post.setLikes(temp + "");
                            Like_unlike.unlike(myPost.getId());
                        }
                    }
                });

        // share post
        holder.like_share_communt.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        customDialogFragment1 cdf = new customDialogFragment1();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("body", postShareUrl
                                + myPost.getId());
                        bundle.putString("subject", myPost.getTitle());
                        cdf.setArguments(bundle);
                        cdf.show(((Activity) context).getFragmentManager(), "customDialogFragment1");


                    }
                });


        if (myPost.getTags().isEmpty()) {
            holder.postTags.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.postTagsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.PostDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.postTags.setText(myPost.getTags());

        }
        if(shouldLaunchGp) {
            GetBitmap gb = new GetBitmap(myPost.getImageIds(), myPost.getVideosIds(),
                    holder.viewPager, holder.linearForDots, holder.linearForViewPager);

            gb.execute();
            setGb(gb);
            shouldLaunchGp=false;
        }

    }else {
        if (type == 1) {
            try {
                final Comment comment = (Comment) postsArray.get(position);
                if (comment.getDescripption().isEmpty()) {
                    row = null;
                } else {
                    holder.commentDate.setText(comment.getDate());
                    holder.commentUserName.setText(comment.getUserName());
                    holder.commentDescription.setText(comment.getDescripption());
                    holder.commentVotesUp.setText(comment.getVotesUp());
                    holder.commentVotesDown.setText(comment.getVotesDown());
                    //0=no like or dislike, 1=like , 2=dislike
                    switch (comment.getLikeStat()) {
                        case 0:
                            holder.commentVotesDownImage.setAlpha(0.65f);
                            holder.commentVotesUpImage.setAlpha(0.65f);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            holder.commentVotesDownImage.setAlpha(0.65f);
                            holder.commentVotesUpImage.setAlpha(1f);
                            holder.commentVotesUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43a047"));
                            holder.commentVotesDown.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp, "Bold");
                            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Regular");
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            holder.commentVotesDownImage.setAlpha(1f);
                            holder.commentVotesDown.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43a047"));
                            holder.commentVotesUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Bold");
                            changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp, "Regular");
                            holder.commentVotesUpImage.setAlpha(0.65f);
                            break;


                    }
                    holder.commentVotesUpImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (v.getAlpha() != 1f) {
                                v.setAlpha(1f);
                                if (holder.commentVotesDownImage.getAlpha() == 1f) {
                                    holder.commentVotesDownImage.performClick();
                                    changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Regular");
                                    holder.commentVotesDown.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                                }
                                changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp, "Bold");
                                holder.commentVotesUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#43a047"));


                                int votesUp = Integer.parseInt(comment.getVotesUp());
                                votesUp++;
                                holder.commentVotesUp.setText(votesUp + "");
                                comment.setVotesUp(votesUp + "");
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentId", comment.getCommentId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", LoginData.getDeviceId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "like"));

                                        try {
                                            jsnp.getJSONFromUrlWithpostParams(commentLike, param);
                                        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }


                                }.execute();

                            } else {
                                v.setAlpha(0.65f);
                                changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp, "Regular");
                                holder.commentVotesUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                                int votesUp = Integer.parseInt(comment.getVotesUp());
                                votesUp--;
                                holder.commentVotesUp.setText(votesUp + "");
                                comment.setVotesUp(votesUp + "");
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentId", comment.getCommentId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", LoginData.getDeviceId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "pin"));
                                        try {
                                            jsnp.getJSONFromUrlWithpostParams(commentLike, param);
                                        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }

                                }.execute();


                            }
                        }
                    });
                    holder.commentVotesDownImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (v.getAlpha() != 1f) {
                                v.setAlpha(1f);
                                if (holder.commentVotesUpImage.getAlpha() == 1f) {
                                    holder.commentVotesUpImage.performClick();
                                    changeFonts(holder.commentVotesUp, "Regular");
                                    holder.commentVotesUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                                }
                                changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Bold");
                                holder.commentVotesDown.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d32f2f"));
                                int votesDown = Integer.parseInt(comment.getVotesDown());
                                votesDown++;
                                holder.commentVotesDown.setText(votesDown + "");
                                comment.setVotesUp(votesDown + "");
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentId", comment.getCommentId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", LoginData.getDeviceId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "dislike"));
                                        try {
                                            jsnp.getJSONFromUrlWithpostParams(commentDislike, param);
                                        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }

                                }.execute();


                            } else {
                                v.setAlpha(0.65f);
                                changeFonts(holder.commentVotesDown, "Regular");
                                holder.commentVotesDown.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
                                int votesDown = Integer.parseInt(comment.getVotesDown());
                                holder.commentVotesDown.setText(votesDown + "");
                                comment.setVotesUp(votesDown + "");
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<>();
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commentId", comment.getCommentId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", LoginData.getDeviceId()));
                                        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "pin"));
                                        try {
                                            jsnp.getJSONFromUrlWithpostParams(commentDislike, param);
                                        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }.execute();


                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("exception","error while loading comments-"+e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return  row;
```

Comment: If you cause memory leaks, they will remain active until you restart AS entirely. Especially when using the emulator, memory use can skyrocket to as much as 4gb easily. Make sure you release unnecessary streams, bitmaps and other resources, prescale your images, use AsyncTask and Services for multi-threading, use static inner classes and use the built in memory recycling methods for adapters. Especially with listviews this can cause major memory issues if you don't.

Comment: hey, ive tryed convert more methods to static but thats didnt help.. Im managing my bitmaps in LruCache. im using MAT and I dont see any memory leaks.. i just cant understand why sometimes when the memory getting close to its max its release it self (you can see small downgrade before the "crazy" ups and down and sometimes its goes like this..

Comment: Can you post the intent creation code and your list's getView method? There are just so many small things that can go wrong here. For example, do the posts contain pictures? If so it could be a problem with a lot of scaling happening on the main thread.

Comment: ive edited my question.. my post contains pictures, most of them loads from the LruCache, other downloaded with asynctask and released in onDestroy..